# manage azure session state data across multiple VMs

Tags: azure, session-state, virtual-machine

I have to host a website on multiple azure virtual machines that are load balanced.I have another SQL server Virtual machine hosting database.  I have to manage user sessions across these multiple servers. I cannot use azure caching technique because it is role based caching. What other options are available to manage session states?

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options:

1) Use [Azure Shared Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh697522.aspx) - this is the original Cache-as-a-Service from Azure and works decently well unless you get to super-high scale scenarios

2) Use [SQL Server-based](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604) session - this should work against your own SQL database running in IAAS VM or against SQL Azure

3) Create your own table storage or blob storage session provider.  There has been an attempt of making on [here](http://azureproviders.codeplex.com/) but it's been long abandoned as far as I know.

Comment: Thanku so much for your help.Need one more suggestion. What if I use traffic manager to load balance the VMs. That way I don't have to manage sessions.What is better option: using shared cache or traffic manager?

Comment: I'm not sure what traffic manager has to do with session.  You're either using session or not.  If you are not using session, then you do not need a session provider.  If you are using session, you need a session provider.  If you're using a round-robin traffic manager approach, you need a single session store provider.  If you're using other traffic manager rules that sticky to a data center, you can implement a session store per data center.  Does this help?